# Order rows by column in joined table in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am trying to order the rows in my friend_profile table by the user's first name ascending (column from the joined user table).

This query fetches the results I need, but how do I maintain the order of the friend_profiles rows based on the first_name field from the user table?

```
SELECT * 
FROM friend_profile 
JOIN user ON friend_profile.id = user.id 
WHERE user.id IN (id1, id2, etc.);
```

Comment: Have you tried:  Order By first_name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to the end of your query `ORDER BY user.first_name ASC`.
Have a look here for more help https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-order-by/

Comment: Didn't realize it was as straight forward as that with the join. Thanks!